# How to create a Debian package for the development version of abcde?

Tags: package-management, packaging, git, abcde

I am one of the developers of the commandline ripper/encoder `abcde`. Development is moving fast and I would like eager Ubuntu `abcde` users to be able to:

1. Create a Debian package from the git head
2. Then update the source with:

   ```
   git pull
   ```

   and subsequently upgrade their installed `abcde` with an *incrementally versioned* upgrade.

The abcde git repository can be accessed as follows:

```
git clone http://git.einval.com/git/abcde.git --depth 1
```

Debian packaging information is already available in the source but the complexity of getting a versioned upgrade that works within the existing Ubuntu packaging structure has so far defeated me...

Comment: Have you looked at the Debian guide on [Packaging with Git](https://wiki.debian.org/PackagingWithGit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to provide packages to your users is by creating a [PPA](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA), especially as you said development is moving fast. It has an option for nightly builds, which you might find desirable.

This way, you can produce stable releases as they come out, and automatically build for several Ubuntu releases and architectures without much trouble.

When development becomes more or less stable, consider including the package in Debian, which will make it available to a wider audience (including Ubuntu and Ubuntu-based distributions).